# Web Service With Missing POST Data Field Is Assumed Empty String

Tags: php, database, web-services, rest, post

A web service consists of CRUD operation. When calling for update operation, optional field which is not being sent to server is considered as empty string or no changes?

For example,

```
function updateMemberProfile(){

    /*
     * $_POST["email"] 
     * $_POST["mobile"] //Optional POST data field
     * $_POST["name"]
     *
     * */

}
```

From above, $_POST["mobile"] is an optional POST data field. If this field is omitted when sending to server, should the "mobile" field be

1. assumed as empty string and update database accordingly?
2. assumed as no changes and ignore this field in the database?

Comment: If you go for `2`, you'd need some OTHER way of emptying out a field, e.g. how would you let a user DELETE the information in a field if an empty field is assumed to be "No change"?

Answer (score 0):

You should assume as no changes and ignore this field in the database. However please take in consideration that the field should not be 'NOT NULL' otherwise you will run in error when you add a row.